# Constant merge issues from release branch to master and back to development

Tags: git, git-flow, merge-conflict-resolution

We have really weird issues with our merge strategies. We are following git flow branching strategies with master, development, feature and release branches. The one thing we haven't done all the time is merge back master branch to development.

This time we wanted to start merge back master to development after the release hoping that this would solve our issues. So we branched out from development to a release branch, created a PR towards master (got conflicts that we resolved). Got a hotfix on the release branch which was merged from a feature branch (based from release branch) and then merged into master when approved. We then merged back to development branch (got only conflict on hotfix issues).

Then just to try things out we created a PR from development to master which in my mind should be ok without any conflicts, but we get conflicts for probably more than 60-70% of the files.

We have tried changing different merge strategies such as rebase no fast-forward, squash commit, basic merge with no fast-forward and so on. It doesn't seem to matter.

Looking at the lastest commithashes development is now one commit ahead of master as it should. What could be the issue? How should we solve this? It shouldn't be a problem having different merge strategies right?

Comment: Mentioning master has to be merged back to development says something is messed up with your git workflow. Work flows from dev to master, not opposite.

Comment: Ryan is correct. If you are following Git Flow (proper noun) then it is per definition impossible to get merge conflicts due to how constrained the merges are. (In fact they are completely trivial but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Are you doing real merges or are you creating fake merge commits with the "squash" option? A "squash merge" is not a real merge and will cause conflicts if merged again.

Comment: My superficial take for your team is to consider a simpler branching strategy since it sounds like a recurring issue. Git Flow is rather formal and is easy for git newbs to "corrupt" (without branch protection + automation tooling). Found a nice writeup about 3 different strategies: https://www.gitkraken.com/learn/git/best-practices/git-branch-strategy

Comment: @knittl's question is right on target.

Comment: We're using squash merge but we have also tried without it. According to gitflow you should merge back from the release branch to development (https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow the release branch section). Since everything is obviously fucked up we need somehow "reset our branch" and how can we do that? Changing branching strategy is not really our decision cause it's decided by the company (weird right?).

Comment: Squash merge would be nice since we don't want all "In-between useless comments from feature branch" but would it be better to rebase interactive before merging? Would that be a more proper "commit"?  

And yes it should be impossible in my world, never experienced this in all my year, and this is becoming a huge problem.

Comment: @Ryan in Git Flow, you *must* merge `master` back to `develop` (or at least `release` back to `develop` which is nearly the same thing). In Git Flow you also don't ever merge `develop` into `master`, but instead you use an in-between `release` branch. If you don't merge `master` (or at least `release`) back down to `develop` after every release, you run into the problems described here.

Comment: @TTT, okay, probably i forgot theory about Git Flow, but logically if we merged `develop` into `release`, succeeded; then merge `release` to `master`, highly likely with success. After that all of the commits located in the `develop`  are already in `develop` - no need to merge. Daily routine merges are done only from `develop` to `topic` branches, just to keep in line with fresh changes and escaping merge conflicts to `develop`. Other work (`develop` -> `release` -> `master`) should go smoothly. It is based on a practice, i don't insist though.

Comment: @Ryan in your stated scenario I agree, but it's not always the case that there are 0 new commits on the `release` branch before merging into `master`.  (In fact I'd consider it rare.) As soon as there is a single bug fix on the `release` branch, then it must make its way back down to `develop` or else it will potentially get undone in subsequent releases.

Answer (score 1):

Normally in Git Flow, it is not possible to have conflicts when merging a `release` branch into `master`. The reason for this is `release` should always be fully up to date with `master`, with the possible exception of some empty merge commits. Note it is possible to have merge conflicts when merging `release`, or `master` back down into `develop`. Hopefully it's rare, but it's certainly possible as a normal course of simultaneous development on two different branches that are eventually merged (e.g. features on `develop` and bug fixes on `release`).

Git Flow usage dictates the following rules anytime a `release` branch is merged into `master`:

1. `release` is merged into `master` using a regular merge. (Not rebase or squash.) Additionally Git-Flow strongly urges you to use `merge --no-ff` to preserve the history of the deployment, and many PR tools default to using `--no-ff` for a regular merge for this reason.
2. ASAP after merging `release` into `master`, you should either merge `release` into `develop` as [documented by Git Flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#finishing-a-release-branch), or, you can merge `master` into `develop`. I prefer the latter so that the new merge commit on `master` is brought down into `develop` "now", which means `develop` and the next `release` branch are fully up to date with `master` in both *state* and *commits*. If you merge `release` into `develop` instead, over time you'll build up multiple empty merge commits on `master` which will finally get brought down to `develop` all in one shot in the future when you finally do a hotfix.

Note for a `hotfix` branch, the rules are similar, but after merging `hotfix` into `master` you should merge `master` into `release` if it exists, or `develop` if there is no pending release branch.

If you always follow those rules it will be impossible to have conflicts when merging `release` into `master`.

**Additional Notes about your scenario specifics:**

> The one thing we haven't done all the time is merge back master branch to development.

As mentioned in rule #2 above, this is *required*. If you skip this step, then any new bug fixes on the `release` branch may not make their way back to `develop`, meaning the next `release` branch may be missing those bug fixes. If you deploy from `release` instead of `master`, you might actually undo those bug fixes in the next release. Also, this opens the door to conflicts the next time you merge `release` into `master` which normally would not be possible.

> We have tried changing different merge strategies such as rebase no fast-forward, squash commit, basic merge with no fast-forward and so on. It doesn't seem to matter.

A similar rule about merge strategies is related to rule #1 above, and this applies to Git in general, not just Git Flow:

> **Git Merge Rule of Thumb:** When merging branch `source` into branch `target`, if `source` is a long-lived *shared* branch, then you should not rewrite the branch.

This means that when performing "Git Flow" merges such as `release` into `master`, `master` into `develop`, etc, you should *never* use rebase or squash, both of which will rewrite the commits on the branch. You should always use a regular merge, and in Git Flow, it's recommended that you also use `--no-ff` even when a fast-forward would be possible. If you rewrite a shared branch it will lead to unnecessary conflicts in future merges.

Note it is OK to use rebase and squash when merging *feature* or *topic* branches into a shared branch, since those branches are not shared and they can be deleted as soon as they are merged into a shared branch. Note for rebase in particular when you have more than 1 commit, Git Flow suggests still forcing a merge commit after the rebase (sometimes called "semi-linear merge"), so that you retain the history of which commits are part of the feature. Squashes and single-commit features have no extra history to retain so it isn't necessary to  have an additional merge commit.

> Then just to try things out we created a PR from development to master which in my mind should be ok without any conflicts, but we get conflicts for probably more than 60-70% of the files.

This will go away as soon as you start following the two Git Flow rules outlined above. Side note, Git Flow doesn't have a documented scenario where you would ever merge `develop` into `master`; instead you should have an in-between `release` branch. (But it's possible for this to happen if your release branch doesn't have any new commits on it after creation from `develop`.)